# YII, when I add a view in a view it uses the parent controller

Tags: php, yii

I have a view in which I want to show a form and a view of another controller. 
So the view 'Bedrijf' holds a 'Vacature' form and a 'Vacature' view.

I could add the form and can call the other controller this way:

```
<?php 
        $model=new Vacature;
        $this->renderPartial('//vacature/_form', array('model'=>$model));
    ?>
```

Only if I add my view the same way it uses the parent (bedrijf) controller:

```
<?php 
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Vacature');
        $this->render('//vacature/index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    ?>
```

How can I make it use it's own controller?

Comment: So your first code works and second does not work?

Comment: yes. The second one gives an error in the url bedrijven/_view. It's looking for bedrijven parameters, which aren't there because vacature/index asks for it... 
I had the same error with the first one when I didn't add the '//vacature/', but for that one this did the trick.

Comment: The view is only a "template" it is not bound directly to a controller. You can call the same view from different controllers. But if you want to insert a view with processing trhoigh another controller, you don't just want to "render" it, but you want to invoke the whole `action`.. how else should this work

Comment: ah, I understand. I called it this way, because I have to use the same template twice. But then it's better to make a widget out of it. Thanks!

Comment: A controller does not belong to a view and vice-vera, although it is convenient to group them together. Normally, in a view, $this-> will refer to the calling controller, if you want another controller other that the one that called render(), look into Yii::app()->createController(). However, I suspect what you really should be looking into is Yii modules : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.module

Answer (score 0):

you can use this line

```
$this->renderPartial('../view_folder/_form', array('model'=>$model));
```

Comment: well, that's the one that's working yes. But I need to include 'vacature/index'. That one uses the 'bedrijven' controller in stead of the 'vacature' controller now...

Comment: add your form action as 'action' => $this->createUrl('controller/action'),